# Permutation Algorithm exampe with contraints

Tags: algorithm, matlab, permutation

I've got a problem that seemed simple, but after spending a day on it (in MatLab) I could'nt work it out.

Consider the set:

```
@   #   ID
--------------
A   3   #1
A   3   #2
B   4   #3
B   4   #4
B   4   #5
C   2   #6
C   2   #7
C   2   #8
C   2   #9
D   1   #10
D   1   #11
E   2   #12
E   2   #13
... ... ...
```

I'd like to find all possible ways to combine the rows of which the second column adds up to a maximum of (and as close as possible to) 5.

Constraints: The first column has to be unique, but I DO need each ID to show up. Order doesn't matter. To give a better idea, here's some examples of wanted and unwanted output (showing is faster than explaining). I'll use the ID column to refer to the row, as the actual output would be a 3D matrix. (so we squeeze the row-dimension here to simplify)

Wanted:

```
#1  #6
#1  #7
#1  #8
#1  #9
#1  #10
#1  #11
#1  #12
#1  #13
#2  #6
#2  #7
#2  #8
#2  #9
#2  #10
#2  #11
#2  #12
#2  #13
```

This would be the start of the wanted output. Everyything adds up to 4 or 5, and where it adds up to 4 (#1 #11 or #2 #10) there are no more valid rows of which the 2nd column can be added.

Unwanted:

```
#6 #7 #10
```

Even though this adds up to 5, the first column is not unique in #5 and #6.

```
#2  #10
#10 #2
```

Sum of 2nd column gets as close to 5 as possible and all letters (1st column) differ within the same row, but they are essentially the same, only in a different order. Permutation of the same combination should be left out (don't care which of the possible arrangements does pop up)

Algorithms I came up with so far only use the first appearens of a "letter" (1st column) or once they found all A-C combinations (first letters which can add up to 5) they go to B and fail to note A-D-E or further possibilities.

EDIT2:

I think I've got it:

```
clearvars

SongList = cell(1,30,23);
m = 0;

for i=1:length(Info_Matrix)-3 % Infomatrix is the set with the @, # and ID. (and a lot more othe rirrelevant columns)

    for k=1:length(Info_Matrix)-i

        clearvars('SongsPlayed')   
        SongsPlayed(1,:) = Info_Matrix(i,:);
        n = 1;
        m = m+1;
        TotalTime = cell2mat(Info_Matrix(i,15));


        for j=i+k:length(Info_Matrix)
            if TotalTime + cell2mat(Info_Matrix(j,15)) > 3600 %In the example we summed up to 5; here we sum up to 3600. If we try to add an element to our current collection that makes the total of the values in column 15 of the given set exceed 3600, do nothing.
            elseif any(strcmp(SongsPlayed(:,1),Info_Matrix(j,1))) %If the name (@) is already in our current collection, do nothing.
            else
                TotalTime = TotalTime + cell2mat(Info_Matrix(j,15));
                n = n+1;
                SongsPlayed(n,:) = Info_Matrix(j,:);
                SongList(m,1:length(SongsPlayed(:,1)),:) = SongsPlayed;
            end
        end

    end

end
```

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds a lot like the knapsack problem. With 13 values you have 13! = 6.2E9 permutations. Did you already find a way to exclude double values?

Comment: seems you can remove #2 #4 #5 #7 #8 #9 #11 #13 already from the start. Since whatever works for #1 must work for #2.

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of buckets. You have 4 buckets with values 1 to 4. In the first bucket there is one bucket with the numbers 10 and 11. In the second bucket are two buckets, one with the values from 6 to 9 and the other with the values 12 and 13. And so on.

We create an array with the values of the outer buckets repeated as many times as there are inner buckets: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

Calculate all desirable combinations: [1, 2, 2], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 3], [4]

Now you have to take all possible combinations of building the combinations above. Except for [2, 3] => [C, A], [E, A] there is only one possibility per combination.

After that you have to combine each number of all the buckets for each combination above, e.g. for [D, C, E] (1, 2, 2) => [10, 11] x [6, 7, 8, 9] x [12, 13] gives 2 * 4 * 2 = 16 combinations.

So there are three steps and each of them is potentially exploding (worse than exponential). This doesn't seem to be feasible no matter how much you optimize it.